# How to move gridview selected row up/down on KeyUp or Keydown press

Tags: c#, datagridview

[image]

1. The user selects one row
2. there will be up arrow and down arrow.
3. If the user wants to move up, the user clicks up arrow button
4. If the user wants to move down, then the user clicks down arrow button
5. if the row is at the top then up arrow button becomes disabled
6. if the row is at the bottom then down arrow button becomes disabled

i tried this code but not at all working for the above scenario

private void key_up(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow == null) return;
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index - 1 >= 0)
    {

        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index - 1].Cells[0];
        dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

the way to do is ,
On key_up or button up clicked
1) Get the current selected row index
2) Set the current  selected row to (index + 1) as long as the index +1 is less than the row count.

Do the negation for the key_Down or button down clicked.

```
    private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Up))
        {
            moveUp();
        }
        if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Down))
        {
            moveDown();
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void moveUp()
    {
        if (dataGridView1.RowCount > 0)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                int rowCount = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
                int index = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Index;

                if (index == 0)
                {
                    return;
                }
                DataGridViewRowCollection rows = dataGridView1.Rows;

                // remove the previous row and add it behind the selected row.
                DataGridViewRow prevRow = rows[index - 1];
                rows.Remove(prevRow);
                prevRow.Frozen = false;
                rows.Insert(index, prevRow);
                dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
                dataGridView1.Rows[index - 1].Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void moveDown()
    {
        if (dataGridView1.RowCount > 0)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                int rowCount = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
                int index = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Index;

                if (index == (rowCount - 2)) // include the header row
                {
                    return;
                }
                DataGridViewRowCollection rows = dataGridView1.Rows;

                // remove the next row and add it in front of the selected row.
                DataGridViewRow nextRow = rows[index + 1];
                rows.Remove(nextRow);
                nextRow.Frozen = false;
                rows.Insert(index, nextRow);
                dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
                dataGridView1.Rows[index + 1].Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

you can see I have separated the move up and down methods, so if you want to use the button clicked events instead of key up and key down event, you can call them when needed.

Comment: actually as per my requirement ....
as show in image above..suppose if i select the highlighted row and i press up key that row should move up and the row above it should come down...

would you please help me in this problem...its very urgent...

Comment: See my edited code, you have to use the Key_Down event not Key_Up event. Also you cannot use this if you are binding datasource to this grid view.

Comment: thanx Jegan..... as per my requirement i modified little bit and it worked for me....

Comment: http://csharpprobsandsoln.blogspot.in/2013/05/how-to-move-gridview-selected-row.html

Answer (score 5):

Cleaned the code of Jegan and made it suitable for multiple datagridviews.

```
    private static void MoveUp(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        if (dgv.RowCount <= 0) 
            return;

        if (dgv.SelectedRows.Count <= 0) 
            return;

        var index = dgv.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Index;

        if (index == 0) 
            return; 

        var rows = dgv.Rows;
        var prevRow = rows[index - 1];
        rows.Remove(prevRow);
        prevRow.Frozen = false;
        rows.Insert(index, prevRow);
        dgv.ClearSelection();
        dgv.Rows[index - 1].Selected = true;
    }

    private static void MoveDown(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        if (dgv.RowCount <= 0) 
            return;

        if (dgv.SelectedRows.Count <= 0) 
            return;

        var rowCount = dgv.Rows.Count;
        var index = dgv.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Index;

        if (index == (rowCount - 2)) // include the header row
            return;

        var rows = dgv.Rows;
        var nextRow = rows[index + 1];
        rows.Remove(nextRow);
        nextRow.Frozen = false;
        rows.Insert(index, nextRow);
        dgv.ClearSelection();
        dgv.Rows[index + 1].Selected = true;
    }
```

Comment: Great. Works a treat.

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked:

```
 public static void MoveUp(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        if (dgv.RowCount <= 0)
            return;

        if (dgv.SelectedRows.Count <= 0)
            return;

        var index = dgv.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Index;

        if (index == 0)
            return;

        var rows = dgv.Rows;
        var prevRow = rows[index - 1];
        rows.Remove(prevRow);
        prevRow.Frozen = false;
        rows.Insert(index, prevRow);
        dgv.ClearSelection();
        dgv.Rows[index - 1].Selected = true;
    }

    public static void MoveDown(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        if (dgv.RowCount <= 0)
            return;

        if (dgv.SelectedRows.Count <= 0)
            return;

        var rowCount = dgv.Rows.Count;
        var index = dgv.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Index;

        if (index == rowCount - 1) // Here used 1 instead of 2
            return;

        var rows = dgv.Rows;
        var nextRow = rows[index + 1];
        rows.Remove(nextRow);
        nextRow.Frozen = false;
        rows.Insert(index, nextRow);
        dgv.ClearSelection();
        dgv.Rows[index + 1].Selected = true;
    }
```

The difference to Mario's code is that I used (rowCount - 1) instead of (rowCount - 2) ... After changing this, it worked perfectly. Before the move-down didn't work if you only have 2 rows in your DataGridView...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very small solution for that issue:

```
    private void DataGridView_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //I use only one function for moving with the information
        //e.KeyCode == Keys.Up = move up, else move down
        if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Up) || e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Down))
        {
            MoveUpDown(e.KeyCode == Keys.Up);
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void MoveUpDown(bool goUp)
    {
        try
        {
            int currentRowindex = DataGridView.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Index;

            //Here I decide to change the row with the parameter
            //True -1 or False +1
            int newRowIndex = currentRowindex + (goUp ? -1 : 1);

            //Here it must be ensured that we remain within the index of the DGV
            if (newRowIndex > -1 && newRowIndex < DataGridView.Rows.Count)
            {
                DataGridView.ClearSelection();
                DataGridView.Rows[newRowIndex].Selected = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }

    }
```

Sorry, I thought my code was self-explanatory.
I hope I made with the comments clear how I proceeded with that issue

Comment: Care to explain what it is your code is doing here, either with comments or a conclusion?

Comment: Is that ok for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the selected row up/down as many times as you want, you can use this code to move:

Up:

```
if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index != 0) {
  for (int j = 0; j < this.dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++) {
    object tmp = this.dataGridView1[j, dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index].Value;
    this.dataGridView1[j, dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index ].Value = this.dataGridView1[j, dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index - 1].Value;
    this.dataGridView1[j, dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index - 1].Value = tmp;
  }
  int a = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
  dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
  this.dataGridView1.Rows[a - 1].Selected = true;
}
```

Down:

```
 if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index != dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2) {
   for (int j = 0; j < this.dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++) {
     object tmp = this.dataGridView1[j, dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index].Value;
     this.dataGridView1[j, dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index].Value = this.dataGridView1[j, dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index + 1].Value;
     this.dataGridView1[j, dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index + 1].Value = tmp;
   }
   int i = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
   dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
   this.dataGridView1.Rows[i + 1].Selected = true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Resumindo mais:

```
private void MoveUpDown(bool goUp)
    {
        int newRowIndex = DataGridView.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Index + (goUp ? -1 : 1);
        if (newRowIndex > -1 && newRowIndex < DataGridView.Rows.Count)
        {
            DataGridView.ClearSelection();
            DataGridView.Rows[newRowIndex].Selected = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post your questions and answers in English. This is a website that is used by many people with different nationalities.

Answer (score 0):

```
    dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;//FullRowSelect
     int selectedrowindexindgv2 =-1;
      private void moveUp()
            {
                if (dataGridView2.RowCount <= 0)
                    return;
    
                if (dataGridView2.SelectedRows.Count <= 0)
                    return;
    
                if (selectedrowindexindgv2 <= 0)
                    return;
    
                DataGridViewRowCollection rows = dataGridView2.Rows;
    
                // remove the previous row and add it behind the selected row.
                DataGridViewRow prevRow = rows[selectedrowindexindgv2 - 1];
                rows.Remove(prevRow);
                prevRow.Frozen = false;
                rows.Insert(selectedrowindexindgv2, prevRow);
                dataGridView2.ClearSelection();
                dataGridView2.Rows[selectedrowindexindgv2 - 1].Selected = true;
                selectedrowindexindgv2 -= 1;
                return;
            }
    
            private void moveDown()
            {
                try
                {
                    if (dataGridView2.RowCount <= 0)
                        return;
    
                    if (dataGridView2.SelectedRows.Count <= 0)
                        return;             
    
                    if (selectedrowindexindgv2 == dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1) // Here used 1 instead of 2
                        return;
    
                    DataGridViewRowCollection rows = dataGridView2.Rows;
                    // remove the next row and add it in front of the selected row.
                    DataGridViewRow nextRow = rows[selectedrowindexindgv2 + 1];
                    rows.Remove(nextRow);
                    nextRow.Frozen = false;
                    rows.Insert(selectedrowindexindgv2, nextRow);
                    dataGridView2.ClearSelection();
                    dataGridView2.Rows[selectedrowindexindgv2 + 1].Selected = true;
                    selectedrowindexindgv2 += 1;
                }catch(Exception) { }
    
            }
    
       private void dataGridView2_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
            {
                if (dataGridView2.Rows.Count > 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        selectedrowindexindgv2 = e.RowIndex;
    }
  private void pictureBox6Up_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            moveUp();
        }

        private void pictureBox7Down_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            moveDown();
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please comment your answer, so that it clarifies, without reading the code listening, what does your approach differ from the others?