# Move selected row to bottom or last row of datagrid WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

[image]So I'm currently doing an automated IQ exam for our HR department. I'm using C# as my P-language and WPF as app foundation. My questions are stored on a mysql database and binded on a datagrid.

My question is, is there a way for me to move a row to the last row? The idea is, when an examiner skips a question, that question goes to the last row of the datagrid. Thanks in advance!

Edit: I've added a picture to explain my idea. Hope it helps!
[image]

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. I've added a picture on my question. Hope it helps sir! :D http://i.stack.imgur.com/BSMM6.png

Comment: Here a related question where the row is moved up/down on arrow up/down button press , you can modify it for your program http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232943/how-to-move-gridview-selected-row-up-down-on-keyup-or-keydown-press

Comment: Thanks sir! I'll give it a try and see if I can make something out of it.

Edit: Hmm, I think this will not work with WPF's datagrid.

Comment: The DataGrid is just a representation of your data. Reorder the items in the collection you're Binding `ItemsSource` to, and the DataGrid will reflect those changes.

Answer (score 0):

try this

YourList.Move(dataGrid.SelectedIndex, dataGrid.Items.Count - 2);

Comment: I tried your code aaannd.. It has an error.

test1dgv.Move(test1dgv.CurrentCell.RowIndex, test1dgv.Items.Count - 1);

Under .Move:
'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' does not contain a definition for 'Move' and no extension method 'Move' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' and on .RowIndex:
'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellInfo' does not contain a definition for 'RowIndex' and no extension method 'RowIndex' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellInfo' could be found

Comment: @ jobyjames85: how can you can  that dataGrid.Items.Count - 2 works for the first record?